# Devise user and messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to create a test rails app with users and messages. I want a one to many relationship between users and messages (a user can have many messages). I have devise used to create the user  and it works (YAY!) and a simple messages model. I added :

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :email
end
```

This is what I think will do the relationship. How do I store the user is with the message that I am creating? and how would I access it? I tried adding a column to the user table and everytime a logged in user tries to send a message, I submit the current user Id with the message. I am not sure this is safe, and it is not very reliable. What is the best/easiest way of doing this?

Comment: What is this column you are referring to on this user table? Do you have user_id on the message table?

Comment: The way I was doing this was probably stupid. I created a user_id column in messages and in the form to create a new message, I make a field in the form and add in the user id and then submit the form.

Comment: My answer below should cover what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## create messages for User

```
user = User.first
user.messages.create(message_params)
```

## access user messages

```
messages = user.messages
```

## do something after User signs in

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_database_authentication do
     # do something
  end
end
```

## message form

```
= simple_form_for current_user.messages.new do |form|
  = form.input :body
  = form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = form.submit 'Leave Message.'
```

## messages controller #create

```
def create
  message = Message.new(message_params)
  if message.save!
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'New message created.'
  else
    redirect_to :back, notice: message.error.join(', ')
  end

private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

User Model:-

```
has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

You can create message of current_user by doing this:-

```
# User Controller:    
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    current_user.messages.build
end

def create
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
        redirect_to success_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:messages_attributes => [:id, :name])
end
```

Can access message of current user:-

```
@messages = current_user.messages
```